# What is this checkboard line on my sequencer timeline that prevents audio from playing?

Tags: video, audio

There is this demarcated area beyond which audio does not work. No idea where it came from or how to remove it. [image: on the right hand side is a checkerboard area that starts in the middle of the yellow area]

Answer (score 2):

I was inside a metastrip. Press  <kbd>Tab</kbd>to exit